# HTML where a new website is launched after successful log in

Tags: html

At work we are having issues with the log in credentials. We use SAP BI and for some reason when logging into the main site, everything works, but when logging into the OpenDoc feature of the site, the credentials do not carry over. The guys are working to fix the credential issues; in the meantime I'm trying to come up with an HTML script workaround that can, after logging into the first site, automatically redirect to the other site. I'm really new to HTML so any help would be appreciated.

This is all I have so far (close to nothing):

window.open("https://login_site.php");

here, after the user inputs the username and password, I want to trigger
the initiation of the second web address. I'm interested on having the
second scripts triggering only after pressing enter, or clicking "Log On" 
without closing the first webpage, otherwise the credentials will be lost-->

window.open("https://redirected_site");

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Baldomero - Are the two sites on the same domain or are they two separate domains? Different domains aren't allowed to access cookies from other domains (for security reasons). If this is the case, there isn't much at all you can do here. You'll need have something coded into the backend that allows Single Sign On (SSO).

Comment: If I leave the first window open, the second window will open just fine without any errors. If I put the user and pass on the first window, the second does not require log in credentials.